# Convergence property of$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$based on the divergence or convergence of$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ and$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check whether $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$  converges to zero knowing that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ diverges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges or oscillates finetely.

[I know that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$  converge or diverge together]

Any clue to proof of this theorem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by "diverges to zero?"

Comment: What is meant by "oscillates finetely" ?

Comment: diverges to zero?

Comment: I think its a pretty common terminology to refer to the "convergence of an infinite product to 0" as "divergence", because it corresponds to a series diverging to $-\infty$. I think that "oscillationg finitely" should mean "bounded", but it is the OPs duty to claify that.

Comment: @RedundantAunt: Thanks. I didn't know that. I have checked it now and did find interesting results.

Comment: If $\prod a_n==0$ although $a_n\ne0$ for every $n$ then the product is said to _diverge_ to $0$. (So for example a convergent infinite product equals $0$ if and only if one of the factors equals $0$.)